# Why does Remix say int256 returned when my function returns int?

Tags: solidity, chainlink

Getting a price feed and returning `int` in my function however Remix is showing the value as `int256` when I call the view function.  Why is this?

Solidity Remix Price Feed Example
[image: Solidity Remix Price Feed Example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

256 is the default length if no length is specified

Answer (score 0):

int is the alias for int256
[Integer in Solidity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fITUO.png)

You can also refer to the [documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.7/types.html) here for more information.